# cakephp with fields search wildcards

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I set an integer variable with a wildcard  for all records. The reason is I need all records sometimes if the id's are not set . My wildcard isnt working.   I currently use an if condition to test if the id is set and there is 4 combinations with 2 variables.

The LIKE option didnt work for me either.

Is there a way to assign a value to the variable to search and this equated to all values like *.* in sql?  For example

```
        $tutorId='*'; 
        $paycycleId='*'; 

         $timesheet=$this->TimeSheet->find('all',array(
               'conditions'=> array ('TimeSheet.tutor_id'=>$tutorId,'TimeSheet.period_start_date'=>$paycycleId ),
               'order' => array('TimeSheet.invoice DESC')) );
```

Comment: Why not just removing the condition? That would be the "correct" wildcard here.

Comment: There is no such thing as an _integer wildcard_.  Follow @mark suggestion and remove the condition if you don't use it.

Comment: you cant remove the condition as what do i do when I have actual values? There is no easy way here I see as I just use if statements as below

Comment: @ajt i updated answer,with Better way to do tasks

Answer (score 1):

If you  want wild search or select All records then use :

**UPDATED Added BETTER way**

//BETTER way ->

```
$conditionsArr = array();

if(CONDITION_SATISFIED){
    $conditionsArr=array('TimeSheet.tutor_id'=>$tutorId,
                         'TimeSheet.period_start_date'=>$paycycleId 
                        );
}

$timesheet=$this->TimeSheet->find('all',
                                   array(
                                        'conditions'=> $conditionsArr,
                                        'order' => array('TimeSheet.invoice DESC')
                                        ) 
                                 );
```

//PREVIOUS WAY ->

```
$conditionsArrEmpty=array();
$conditionsArr=array('TimeSheet.tutor_id'=>$tutorId,
                     'TimeSheet.period_start_date'=>$paycycleId 
                    );

//With Wildcard (Select All records)
$timesheet=$this->TimeSheet->find('all',
                                   array(
                                        'conditions'=> $conditionsArrEmpty,
                                        'order' => array('TimeSheet.invoice DESC')
                                        ) 
                                 );
```

//With Acutal conditions

```
$timesheet=$this->TimeSheet->find('all',
                                   array(
                                        'conditions'=> $conditionsArr,
                                        'order' => array('TimeSheet.invoice DESC')
                                        ) 
                                 );
```